# All initial segments of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Q)Find all initial segments of the given list [1, 3, 6 ,9, 8]. i.e. [], [1], [1,3],[1,3,6]

I'm stuck on how to construct the recursive call to segments,I know I have to use an append function but not sure how to bring it all together, I have the following code:

```
append([], L, L).
append([H|L1], L2, [H|L3]):-
  append(L1, L2, L3). 


segments([],[]).
segments([H|L1],R):-
```

Comment: `append/3` already gives you those segments one by one upon backtracking: `append(Segment, _, L)`. You may use `findall/3` to gather all of them on a list.

Comment: Thankyou! Makes sense now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that @gusbro's solution with `append/3` as well as @brebs answer work well if the initial list is given, however, both permit also other solutions that are not lists.

```
?- L = [1|non_list], append(Segment, _, L).
   L = [1|non_list], Segment = []
;  L = [1|non_list], Segment = [1]
;  false.
?- L = non_list, append(Segment, _, L).
   L = non_list, Segment = []
;  false.
```

So even `non_list` works ; that is a term that is as far remote from a list as possible. Often such extra unwanted generalizations are accepted, in particular if you know that you will never rely upon it. Also this is know as a [**list prefix**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#7.1.6.9) of a term.

But if you want to be sure that only lists are considered, use Prolog's [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)-formalism which is the method of choice in many areas.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars). % to make "strings" readable

... --> [] | [_], ... . % any sequence

seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).

segment_of(Xs, Zs) :-
   phrase((seq(Xs), ...), Zs).

?- segment_of(Xs, "abc").
   Xs = []
;  Xs = "a"
;  Xs = "ab"
;  Xs = "abc"
;  false.
?- segment_of(Xs, non_list).
   false.
?- segment_of("ab", L).
   L = "ab"
;  L = [a,b,_A]
;  L = [a,b,_A,_B]
;  L = [a,b,_A,_B,_C]
;  ... .
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using append:

```
% Inc can be an empty list, if Lst is a list (empty or not)
increasing_list([], []).
increasing_list([_|_], []).

increasing_list(Lst, Inc) :-
    increasing_list_(Lst, Inc).

% Unify Inc with the current element (Head) of Lst
increasing_list_([Head|_Tail], [Head]).

% Add Head element from Lst to Inc
increasing_list_([Head|Tail], [Head|Inc]) :-
    % Loop through the elements in Lst
    increasing_list_(Tail, Inc).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- increasing_list([1, 3, 6 ,9, 8], Inc).
Inc = [] ;
Inc = [1] ;
Inc = [1,3] ;
Inc = [1,3,6] ;
Inc = [1,3,6,9] ;
Inc = [1,3,6,9,8]
```

Comment: same thing can be coded simpler and equivalently as `increasing_list(_Lst, []).`
`increasing_list([Head|Tail], [Head|Tail2]) :- increasing_list(Tail, Tail2).`